# How to setup SqlDependency to monitor multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sqldependency

I am trying to figure out how to monitor more than one table with a SqlDependency.  All the examples I have found are for one table.

I have multiple classes that represent a monitor for a specific table.  Each time a change event is raised I stop the dependency and start a new one but that unhooks the other monitors.  How do I get it to keep monitoring for multiple tables?  Do I need to re-hookup all the monitors each time an event is caught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AggregateCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aggregatecachedependency%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class to setup dependency on multiple tables.